# Execute script when opening new terminal IntelliJ Idea

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, cmd, terminal

In my idea terminal (based on windows) I use an alias `doskey ll=dir` each time I open a new terminal (so if i prompt `ll` make a `dir`).

There is a way to execute by default a command (a script will be better) when opening a new terminal?

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request, feel free to vote:

- [IDEA-159562](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159562) Configure starting script / prelude for embedded terminal

At the moment you can try creating a batch file that will start the terminal and pass it the script to execute, then specify this batch file as your **Shell path** in `Tools` | `Terminal`.

Comment: sample batch file to use as Shell path: cmd.exe /k C:\path\to\my\script.bat